# More wifi issues - Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 ath10k_pci

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros

My wifi has actually worked well until recently. I had put the files from kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git in /lib/firmware as per 
[No Wifi in Qualcom Atheros - Ubuntu 16.04 - Acer Aspire E 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15) and [Problems with Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770897/problems-with-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-in-ubuntu-16-04) and others.

However, I still have major problems. Even plugging in a wifi dongle has issues, but one problem at a time - problem is definitely this device. The rest of the devices on my network are totally fine.

Running Ubuntu 16.10 on Acer Aspire V15 Nitro laptop.

```
jonathan@melange:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e09d]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:1039]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
[    5.777028] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    6.058560] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:07:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    6.058568] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:07:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    6.061957] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 105b:e09d
[    6.061959] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    6.062416] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4-00022-QCARMSWPZ-2 api 5 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 4d458559
[    6.128304] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to fetch board data for bus=pci,bmi-chip-id=0,bmi-board-id=0 from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
[    6.129084] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id 0:0 crc32 ed5f849a
[    8.181802] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[    8.181838] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: htt-ver 3.32 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    9.207221] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: suspend timed out - target pause event never came
[    9.292828] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0 wlp7s0: renamed from wlan0
[   11.516595] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   14.579410] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set rx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[   17.651411] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[   23.795416] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   26.083746] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   29.171309] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   35.315207] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   37.602389] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   40.691216] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set tx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[   43.763273] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
```

Comment: I encounter this in Dell Inspiron 15, 5000series. using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you may be suffering from a couple different issues.  I want you to reinstall the Ubuntu package linux-firmware as that may be more up to date than kvallo's github site

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

A recent change to network manager enables wifi powersave by default, to disable this do

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: Is `skip_otp=y` helpful?

Comment: Ok I found that simply deleting the ath10k folder in /lib/firmware then doing the reinstall of linux-firmware helped, as there must of been some of my mods that were causing issues. I'm not sure the powersave is an issue though, as I can't tell if it makes a difference.  I think we're working again now. Thanks

Comment: @chili555 that might be taken care of in firmware now `features wowlan,ignore-otp`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Ahh! Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @jonathanbsyd How did you delete the firmware for your wi-fi driver and reinstall the firmware afterwards?

Comment: @J.Mini you might want to ask your own question as this is no longer relevant

Comment: @J.Mini this question is nearly 7 years old. As a fresh question with your own specific issues. This is ancient history now.