# 19.10 Wi-Fi stops almost after every page load

Tags: networking, wireless, 19.10

Until recently my Wi-Fi has worked with no problems for years. Now it is constantly stopping - almost after every page load. I can't even run 'sudo apt update' without it stopping. The only way to restart it is with `service network-manager restart` and then it takes a random amount of restarts (anything from 5 to 20) until it will stabilise for a few minutes and then start dropping again.

Happens on all types of networks - 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz - in different countries or on the same network in different llocations

I have also replaced the `board-2.bin` and `firmware-6.bin` files inside `/lib/firmware/ath10k` with the ones from kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git as in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1743279) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878097/more-wifi-issues-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-ath10k-pci?rq=1), and the links therein. That didn't help, although I don't know whether I have done it correctly as there are many files in the kvalo git repository.

I also tried simply deleting the `atk10k` folder inside `lib/firmware` and then reinstalling `linux-firmware`. That didn't help either

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k

3b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Device [0707:2400]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
--
3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
[    3.197238] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[    3.197240] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    3.197707] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1.c3-00059 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad,raw-mode,mfp crc32 3c85e1f9
[    3.262836] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 4ac0889b
[    3.319631] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    3.337653] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: htt-ver 3.62 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    3.796612] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0 wlp60s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.873223] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 1092.213500] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[ 1092.213507] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[ 1092.213509] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[ 1095.285386] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: wmi command 24579 timeout, restarting hardware
[ 1095.296049] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to read hi_board_data address: -16
[ 1098.341819] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
[ 1101.369278] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
[ 1101.369281] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to wait for target init: -110
[ 1101.370329] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
[ 1101.370476] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to delete peer cc:d4:a1:e1:3b:66 for vdev 0: -108
[ 1101.370555]  crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 ath10k_pci crypto_simd nvidia(POE) cryptd mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_rawmidi ath10k_core glue_helper snd_seq ath intel_cstate snd_seq_device i915 mac80211 intel_rapl_perf snd_timer dell_wmi rtsx_pci_ms dell_smbios dcdbas joydev wmi_bmof drm_kms_helper intel_wmi_thunderbolt cfg80211 input_leds snd serio_raw sparse_keymap memstick dell_wmi_descriptor drm mxm_wmi ipmi_devintf processor_thermal_device ipmi_msghandler i2c_algo_bit intel_rapl_common libarc4 fb_sys_fops mei_me syscopyarea sysfillrect mei intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf sysimgblt soundcore int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel dell_rbtn mac_hid acpi_pad nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables
[ 1101.370755] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[ 1101.370756] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set cts protection for vdev 0: -108
[ 1101.370757] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set erp slot for vdev 0: -108
[ 1101.370758] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set preamble for vdev 0: -108
[ 1101.370759] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to down vdev 0: -108
[ 1101.370760] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to submit vdev param txbf 0x0: -108
[ 1101.370761] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalc txbf for vdev 0: -108
[ 1101.629359] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
[ 2049.381048] ath10k_warn: 8 callbacks suppressed
[ 2049.381050] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[ 2049.381053] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[ 2049.381054] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[ 2052.453106] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: wmi command 24579 timeout, restarting hardware
[ 2052.533760] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
[ 2052.534360] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to delete peer cc:d4:a1:e1:3b:66 for vdev 0: -108
[ 2052.534471] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[ 2052.534473] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set cts protection for vdev 0: -108
[ 2052.534475] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set erp slot for vdev 0: -108
[ 2052.534476] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set preamble for vdev 0: -108
[ 2052.788943] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
[22430.835210] ath10k_warn: 11 callbacks suppressed
[22430.835217] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[22430.835223] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[22430.835227] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[22433.907152] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: wmi command 24579 timeout, restarting hardware
[22433.987003] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
[22433.987174] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to delete peer cc:d4:a1:e1:3b:66 for vdev 0: -108
[22433.987301] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[22433.987303] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set cts protection for vdev 0: -108
[22433.987305] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set erp slot for vdev 0: -108
[22433.987307] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set preamble for vdev 0: -108
[22434.243109] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
[22515.057310] ath10k_warn: 11 callbacks suppressed
[22515.057316] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[22515.057321] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[22515.057324] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[22518.385246] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: wmi command 24579 timeout, restarting hardware
[22518.435343] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device has crashed during init
[22518.463308] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device has crashed during init
[22518.463313] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to wait for target init: -70
[22518.465767] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
[22518.466026] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to delete peer cc:d4:a1:e1:3b:66 for vdev 0: -108
[22518.466207] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[22518.728260] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
[22554.480417] ath10k_warn: 14 callbacks suppressed
[22554.480424] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[22554.480432] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[22554.480437] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[22557.808265] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: wmi command 24579 timeout, restarting hardware
[22557.858429] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device has crashed during init
[22557.886374] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device has crashed during init
[22557.886379] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to wait for target init: -70
[22557.888744] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
[22557.889006] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to delete peer cc:d4:a1:e1:3b:66 for vdev 0: -108
[22557.889194] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[22558.152596] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
[22604.399236] ath10k_warn: 14 callbacks suppressed
[22604.399251] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[22604.399261] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[22604.399263] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[22607.727119] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: wmi command 24579 timeout, restarting hardware
[22607.811144] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
[22607.811336] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to delete peer cc:d4:a1:e1:3b:66 for vdev 0: -108
[22607.811435] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[22607.811437] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set cts protection for vdev 0: -108
[22607.811439] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set erp slot for vdev 0: -108
[22607.811440] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set preamble for vdev 0: -108
[22608.069194] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
[22684.525426] ath10k_warn: 11 callbacks suppressed
[22684.525431] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[22684.525436] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[22684.525439] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[22687.853319] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: wmi command 24579 timeout, restarting hardware
[22687.903404] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device has crashed during init
[22687.931367] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device has crashed during init
[22687.931370] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to wait for target init: -70
[22687.932561] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
[22687.932747] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to delete peer cc:d4:a1:e1:3b:66 for vdev 0: -108
[22687.932827] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[22688.189084] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
[22725.996479] ath10k_warn: 14 callbacks suppressed
[22725.996485] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[22725.996492] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[22725.996495] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[22729.324375] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: wmi command 24579 timeout, restarting hardware
[22732.372242] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
[22735.400184] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
[22735.400189] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to wait for target init: -110
[22735.401173] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
[22735.401355] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to delete peer cc:d4:a1:e1:3b:66 for vdev 0: -108
[22735.401417] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[22735.401418] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set cts protection for vdev 0: -108
[22735.401420] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set erp slot for vdev 0: -108
[22735.401420] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set preamble for vdev 0: -108
[22735.401422] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to down vdev 0: -108
[22735.401423] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to submit vdev param txbf 0x0: -108
[22735.401423] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalc txbf for vdev 0: -108
[22735.659418] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
```

As per request

```
iwconfig

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

wlp60s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MOVISTAR_PLUS_3B5D"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.3 GHz  Access Point: CC:D4:A1:E1:3B:66   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:65   Missed beacon:0

enp59s0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.
```

As per request

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Also the output of `journalctl | fgrep PCI` , which keeps printing messages all the time, but as far as I can see it just repeats the same snippet, which I have coppied at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/PByZAxM8).

Moreover, the output of `journalctl --list-boots`. Again a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/PaKp1ySw)

The output of `journalctl -b 0 | fgrep PCI`. Another [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/EhEQYZg6)

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `iwconfig`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Done.

Comment: results for `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Added

Comment: for a long shot `journalctl | fgrep PCI` please.

Comment: @nobody That command just keeps printing messages. Not sure how to include its output

Comment: @nobody I added a pastebin link to the snippet that it seems the command repeats

Comment: Really, Aug? You have persistend Journaling?   `journalctl --list-boots`  please

Comment: @nobody I added another pastebin link with the requested information. I don't really understand what these commands do and I have no idea why it says Aug in the output

Comment: @nobody Oh sorry, I just realised that if I let `journalctl --list-boots` print stuff it eventually reaches December and stops. Shall I include all the outputs?

Comment: you have persistent journaling.  I have to ask different. `journalctl -b 0 | fgrep PCI` please.

Comment: @nobody I have added it. Shall I delete the previous two pastebins from the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102220/discussion-between-nobody-and-thunderbiggi).