# Qualcomm QCA6174 unstable wifi and bluetooth

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I'm running into issue with my Wifi on my new laptop (Surface Laptop 3) the quality of the Wifi/Bluetooth is terrible (can't keep a hold of the signal 1 meter away from the AP).

Running Ubuntu 20.04, but also tried 19.10 and Fedora 31 with the exact same results. It works perfectly under Windows 10 (reinstalled it to test that).

lspci:
`02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)`

I already installed linux-firmware  but it shows that error in dmesg: `failed to fetch board data for bus=pci,vendor=168c,device=003e,subsystem-vendor=045e,subsystem-device=0001 from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin`

dmesg | grep ath:

```
[    3.048404] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.329884] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 045e:0001
[    3.329887] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    3.330360] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[    3.395007] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to fetch board data for bus=pci,vendor=168c,device=003e,subsystem-vendor=045e,subsystem-device=0001 from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
[    3.395212] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 ed5f849a
[    3.467544] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    3.489827] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    3.575198] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x0
[    3.575199] ath: EEPROM indicates default country code should be used
[    3.575200] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[    3.575201] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[    3.575201] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[    3.575201] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[    3.579048] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.692769] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
```

uname -a

```
Linux FX-Surface-Laptop-3 5.4.0-surface-devel-191228 #3 SMP Sat Dec 28 22:44:23 +08 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is a custom Kernel to solve other issues related to Surfaces but the stock kernel already had the Wireless issues.

So far I followed solutions from [More wifi issues - Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 ath10k_pci](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878097/more-wifi-issues-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-ath10k-pci) and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1520343?comments=all but without success.

Comment: Has the same issue on RedmiBook 14 Rizen Eddition.

Answer (score 0):

It needs a custom firmware, solved it by using https://github.com/thebitstick/surfacego-wifi