# Xiaomi RedmiBook 14" Ryzen Edition broken WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros

Running

```
Linux RedmiBook 5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci reports the device

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
```

dmesg shows following messages when modprobe ath10_pci

```
[   35.405479] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   35.677189] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0847
[   35.677191] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   35.677655] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[   35.741238] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to fetch board data for bus=pci,vendor=168c,device=003e,subsystem-vendor=11ad,subsystem-device=0847 from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
[   35.741396] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 ed5f849a
[   35.813765] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   35.832637] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
ko
```

as a result no wifi no networks visible and no connection possible

P.S.
Posted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1860552)

Comment: Similar issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200550/qualcomm-qca6174-unstable-wifi-and-bluetooth

Comment: See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=919652

Comment: Does not solve an issue.

Comment: What do you mean? What did you do? That report explains the issue and probides a couple of solutions. They are not one click ones.

Comment: You can report a bug by running `ubuntu-bug linux-frimware`.

Comment: Trying to replace firmware files and restart ath10k_pci

Comment: You have a bit different device. You can use that post as a guide.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1860552

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me except:

```
sudo wget http://www.killernetworking.com/support/K1535_Debian/board.bin -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1/firmware-6.bin_WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00132-QCARMSWP-1 -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
```

Now I finally can use WiFi on Redmibook 13 Ryzen Edition. Contact me if you still have this issue.