# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS wireless internet problem No network devices available

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager

I'm Ubuntu 16.04 user. My problem is that I cannot connect to wireless internet. My system cannot catch wifi. Whenever I check network-manager, it just shows the message No network devices available. I tried many ways on the internet but couldn't fix this problem. I also disabled avahi deamon. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my labtop please?

```
kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ ifconfig
    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:23920 (23.9 KB)  TX bytes:23920 (23.9 KB)

kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ sudo network-manager restart
[sudo] password for kimhojoon: 
sudo: network-manager: command not found
kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ sudo service network-manager restart
kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
bash: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf: Permission denied
kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ sudo lshw -C Network
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 32
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:d1000000-d11fffff

kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ sudo dhclient
[sudo] password for kimhojoon: 
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ ifconfig -a
enx002017031993 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:20:17:03:19:93  
          inet addr:192.168.219.104  Bcast:192.168.219.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7941:f919:37eb:72b8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1273 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:973 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:663941 (663.9 KB)  TX bytes:157943 (157.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5166 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5166 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:541852 (541.8 KB)  TX bytes:541852 (541.8 KB)
kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ ping -c5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=58.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=61.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=42 time=69.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=42 time=52.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=42 time=49.5 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 49.516/58.351/69.495/6.984 ms
kimhojoon@kimhojoon-14Z970-LR1EK:~$ host 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer google-public-dns-a.google.com.
```

Comment: There are two possible solutions within the forum: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/929027/qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-802-11ac-wireless-network-adapter-168c003e-rev-32`  and  `https://askubuntu.com/questions/770897/problems-with-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-in-ubuntu-16-04`.

Some careful reading may resolve this for you.

Comment: @Piloti The OP might have problems going to your reference pages.  They don't appear as links.  I'm reentering the pages as links> 
Piloti suggested pages are:  https://askubuntu.com/q/929027/29012 and https://askubuntu.com/q/770897/29012 .

Comment: Will you add the output of: `ping -c5 8.8.8.8` and the output of `host 8.8.8.8` to your question?