# Problem in WIFI adapter not found

Tags: networking, drivers

I cant able to use WIFI in ubuntu LTS 20.04 operating system, Please help me on this to fix the issue.

As of now i am using the USB tethering.

I have ran command below:-

**"sudo lshw|grep -A15 'network|Wireless' && lspci | grep BCM && sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A2"**

The results below for above command:-

```
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            logical name: enp1s0
            version: 15
            serial: 9c:5a:44:38:16:cf
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
            resources: irq:30 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
    *-pci:1

       *-network UNCLAIMED
            description: Network controller
            product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            version: 31
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
    *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
         description: Encryption controller
         product: Carrizo Platform Security Processor
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 8
         bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
         version: 00

               description: Wireless interface
               product: Android
               vendor: Android
               physical id: 2
               bus info: usb@2:2
               version: 3.18
               serial: 83e3de9d7d34
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=rndis_host maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
       *-usbhost:1
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 5.4.0-42-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@3
            logical name: usb3
            version: 5.04



*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 02:4d:d1:2b:75:be
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.200 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: Please try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770897/problems-with-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-in-ubuntu-16-04) answer and report back. You might need to name your folder `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377`

Comment: Hi Raffles, your are told me to create folders under **firmware** as ath10k/QCA9377.  Already the folder was present **/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377**

Comment: These problems are usually due to kernel, drivers or having secure boot enabled in BIOS/UEFI. Can you say what machine it is?

Comment: My device is _Lenovo E4125_, Yes it's **UEFI mode** only, But in BIOS settings i have _disabled the_ **secure boot**. Kindly let me know if there is any solution for this issue

Comment: Will try my best. Your UEFI mode and BIOS settings should be good. Do you see any drivers in the `Additional Drivers` tab in `Software and Updates`?

Comment: And please make sure that there isn't a physical switch on your machine, usually a function key, which switches the WiFi on and off.

Comment: There is no update in **Additional drivers** tab, I have already checked. There is no physical switch also.                                                                              
FYI, when I am using external WIFI adapter its working, build in adapter is not working. I think the latest ubuntu version only i  faced the issue, pervious version the wifi is working